# Can't trigger `onBackPressed` and `onKeyDown` when ProgressDialog bar is showing

Tags: android

I'm stuck in a strange problem, I have a `ProgressDialog` and when it's in showing with `dialog.setCancelable(false);` I  can't trigger `onBackPressed` or `onKeyDown`. I have such a scenario where progress is showing but when press on back button to run some code. Any help is apreciated!

Comment: any coments, why down votes?

Comment: You should probably add some code to show what you've already tried. Not doing this usually results in down votes.

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix the code is trivial, I explained mentioning most important used code...

Comment: I'm just saying that some people instantly downvote when they see no code. So I'm guessing that's what's caused some downvotes

Answer (score 1):

As Android dialogue class `BackPress` method show

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mCancelable) {
           // cancle and it will return
        }
 }
```

So it will not do any thing on `onBackPress()` or key event if setCanclable is set true

you just need to create dialogue class which extend Dialogue and just need to override that `onBackPress()` method and keyevent like

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyDialog(Context context, myOnClickListener myclick) {
        super(context);
        this.myListener = myclick;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.alert);
    }
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed()
   {

     // do thing which you want to do on back press
   }
  // same for key 
}
```

Hope This help

Answer (score 0):

If you want your dialog to not be cancelable with only touches use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` instead of `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

You should then be able to still use the backbutton. Note that you will have to override `OnBackPressed` to suppress the default behavior of closing the dialog.

Comment: thx for response but this doesn't fit my usecase, ProgressDialog  must still showing but I need to trigger on back button...

Comment: That's why I mentioned you'll have to suppress the default behavior. It will not work otherwise.

Comment: YEah, you probably meant `setOnCancelListener()`

Comment: No I didn't, you should override `OnBackButtonPressed()` in your Activity. But see @mayur-raval his answer. It's a more clean solution anyway.